# How to assign Json Passed Date Value to Java Date Object

Tags: java, json, hibernate, extjs4

my java pojo class is

```
public class Task implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private Integer priority;
private Double duration;
private Integer percentDone;
private String durationUnit;
private Integer parentId;
private String taskName;
private Integer taskindex;
private Integer depth;

public Task() {
}

public Task(Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer priority,
        Double duration, Integer percentDone, String durationUnit,
        Integer parentId, String taskName, Integer taskindex, Integer depth) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.percentDone = percentDone;
    this.durationUnit = durationUnit;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.taskindex = taskindex;
    this.depth = depth;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "StartDate", length = 10)
public Date getStartDate() {
    return this.startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "EndDate", length = 10)
public Date getEndDate() {
    return this.endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

@Column(name = "Priority")
public Integer getPriority() {
    return this.priority;
}

public void setPriority(Integer priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

@Column(name = "Duration", precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Double getDuration() {
    return this.duration;
}

public void setDuration(Double duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

@Column(name = "PercentDone")
public Integer getPercentDone() {
    return this.percentDone;
}

public void setPercentDone(Integer percentDone) {
    this.percentDone = percentDone;
}

@Column(name = "DurationUnit", length = 20)
public String getDurationUnit() {
    return this.durationUnit;
}

public void setDurationUnit(String durationUnit) {
    this.durationUnit = durationUnit;
}

@Column(name = "parentId")
public Integer getParentId() {
    return this.parentId;
}

public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

@Column(name = "TaskName")
public String getTaskName() {
    return this.taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

@Column(name = "Taskindex")
public Integer getTaskindex() {
    return this.taskindex;
}

public void setTaskindex(Integer taskindex) {
    this.taskindex = taskindex;
}

@Column(name = "depth")
public Integer getDepth() {
    return this.depth;
}

public void setDepth(Integer depth) {
    this.depth = depth;
}
```

my util which will assign values from my jsonObject to Pojo is

```
JSONUtils.getMorpherRegistry().registerMorpher(new DateMorpher(new String[] {"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}));
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(data);
    System.out.println("JSON OBJECT VALUE FOR PARENTID ::"+jsonObject.get("parentId"));

    jsonObject.put("taskName", jsonObject.getString("Name"));
    jsonObject.put("startDate", jsonObject.get("StartDate"));
    jsonObject.put("endDate", jsonObject.get("EndDate"));
    jsonObject.put("duration", jsonObject.getInt("Duration"));
    jsonObject.put("durationUnit", jsonObject.getString("DurationUnit"));
    jsonObject.put("percentDone", jsonObject.getInt("PercentDone"));
    jsonObject.put("priority", jsonObject.getInt("Priority"));



    jsonObject.put("parentId", jsonObject.getInt("parentId"));
    jsonObject.put("taskindex", jsonObject.getInt("index"));
    jsonObject.put("depth", jsonObject.getInt("depth"));

    jsonObject.remove("Id");
    jsonObject.remove("ManuallyScheduled");
    jsonObject.remove("checked");
    jsonObject.remove("Name");
    jsonObject.remove("StartDate");
    jsonObject.remove("EndDate");
    jsonObject.remove("Duration");
    jsonObject.remove("DurationUnit");
    jsonObject.remove("PercentDone");
    jsonObject.remove("Priority");
    jsonObject.remove("index");

    System.out.println("JSON OBJECT ::"+jsonObject);

    Task newTask = (Task) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Task.class);
```

and my jsonObject I am receiving to my server side is

```
{
"parentId": 0,
"depth": 1,
"taskName": "New Task",
"startDate": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
"endDate": "2012-01-31T00:00:00",
"duration": 1,
"durationUnit": "d",
"percentDone": 60,
"priority": 1,
"taskindex": 5 }
```

don't know why I am not able to assign the startDate to my startDate POJO object.

when i remove the **JSONUtils.getMorpherRegistry().registerMorpher(new DateMorpher(new String[] {"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}));**

values are assigned to my POJO object and everything works fine but startDate changes to current Date and then it is assigned. and I am getting warking to my server side as

```
WARNING: Can't transform property 'startDate' from java.lang.String into java.util.Date. Will register a default Morpher INFO: Property 'java.util.Date.class' has no write method. SKIPPED. WARNING: Property 'java.lang.String.date' does not exist. SKIPPED. INFO: Property 'java.util.Date.day' has no write method. SKIPPED.  WARNING: Property 'java.lang.String.hours' does not exist. SKIPPED. WARNING: Property 'java.lang.String.minutes' does not exist. SKIPPED.  WARNING: Property 'java.lang.String.month' does not exist. SKIPPED. WARNING: Property 'java.lang.String.seconds' does not exist. SKIPPED.  INFO: Property 'java.util.Date.timezoneOffset' has no write method. SKIPPED.
```

after this when i print the POJO assign value i am getting the **startDate as Thu Jan 12 10:09:27 IST 2012** and **endDate as Thu Jan 12 10:09:27 IST 2012**

so what's the problem in assign the jsonObject to my Pojo Date object

Comment: Can you post what exact problem is reported by database ?

Comment: hi.. tejas i modified my question with all necessary details

Answer (score 1):

Your DateMorpher format string is incorrect, try this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

for more see java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: The problem with for `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` is that , `SimpleDatFormat` doesn't recognizes `T` character and throws exception.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I tried to use your DateMorpher format but it didn't work at all. Same I am not able to assign the Json Data to my Java POJO object. my java pojo class with startDate and endDate **private Date startDate;
 private Date endDate;**

Comment: TejasArjun is correct the T character needs to be surrounded by quotes - I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use StringTokenizer with T as delimiter, to get the Date part and then create Date object.

Comment: Hi I am still having the same problem I am receiving the date in format of **2012-01-30T00:00:00** so how can I assign it to my Date variable startDate in JAVA. ??

Comment: If it's possible to get the date in long format, then go for that way. It would then be easier to convert a long date to java.util.Date

Comment: Other point, the current date format is the one used in XML Schema.

Answer (score 0):

Gson gson=new Gson();
YourEntityClass e_class=gson.fromJson(JsonData,YourEntityClass.class);
may can help you.

Comment: actually i am using extjs 4 with mvc and passing data to my server using json so might be the problem with encoded date ?? Do you have any solution for this.

Comment: I have parsed json from server by Gson to Client in this way.i hope to give you some tips but.. i am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in the    DateMorpher class, the Date you pass in arguments is put into lowercase (I don't understand why), so the real pattern should be    "yyyy-MM-dd't'HH:mm:ss". Hope this helps.